# Accessing to non visible database backup

Tags: google-cloud-sql, database-backups

I use Google Cloud Platform, I have database backups scheduled once a day between 1 to 5 am. It had always worked well but today when I accessed it, it said I had many pages of backups.

In the first one I could see the backups of the last week and when I jump to the second one it jumps to February 1st and then to November and I really need the other backups.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic backups are daily, incremental and auto deleted. There is a maximum of 7, which means that you can recover up to a week. These backups are the ones that I suppose that you see on your first page.

On-demand backups are only saved when you request them. You can read more detailed information about both backup types [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups).

I suppose that the older ones that you see were taken manually and that you expected to be able to access automated backups older than 7 days. You should manually create them on the crucial dates for your development environment.